# Determination of sub-polygon from line segments with known member connectivity

Tags: geometry, polygons

I am trying to determine a way to detect sub-polygons given the information of member connectivity. The sub-polygons are actually the floor panels of a building/industrial structure plan and the line segments are crisscrossing beams.

Consider the following polygon as attached

[image: Example of a polygon]]

Let the known parameter be as follows:

- Member to member connectivity, i.e. it is known that A – E, X – E, F – B,   etc. for all the members.
- All the space co-ordinates (x, y, z) for each co-ordinate is known.

Note that we do not know which members form the sub-polygon(s).

Given this information, I want to find all the edges and vertices which make up each of the sub-polygons, or in mathematical terms:

***EDGES () = A-E, X-E, E-C etc. and VERTICES () = A, X, E, C etc.***

***CAL_SUB_POLY (EDGES, VERTICES) = POLY(A-E-X-G), POLY(A-G-D), POLY(X-E-C-G) and POLY(G-D-F-B-C)***

Please note that the polygon shown here is just one case for illustration. The complexity may expand with increase in generality. Could it be possible to make a general algorithm for n-vertices and k-edges. I have looked into meshing algorithms like winged-edge technique and delaunay triangulation , but I cannot find anything relevant. In most meshing algorithms, the technique is used to create a data structure which stores the info of all mesh given that we already know which edges make the surface; thus those techniques are an effective method of storing and accessing that information, not in sub-polygon determination.

I am actually a structural engineer who develops engineering algorithms and this current assignment is a bit complex as I am not very familiar with combinatoric geometry or graph theory.

I would be very grateful for any hint in the correct direction.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: In a way, meshing algorithms are irrelevant because their job _is already done_ and presented to you in the form of connectivity data.

Comment: Yes that's correct. My job is sort of the reverse of that...

Comment: There are lots of papers on graph theory and cycle or circuit finding, and quite a few *graph cycle* questions here. However, I have an idea based on a different approach, polygon simplification: First, find the perimeter polygon. Then, remove the shortest cycle (or any cycle of length 3) with one or more edges shared with the perimeter polygon (this being one tile or sub-polygon), also editing the perimeter polygon to reflect the smaller net left after the removal. Repeat until you're left with a single simple cycle; that is the final sub-polygon or tile.

Comment: @NominalAnimal The problem starts at _"remove the shortest cycle"_, since we don't know our cycles yet.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Actually, no, not in my idea. Finding *"the shortest cycle with one or more edges shared with the perimeter polygon"* is simpler, because it can be done as a breadth-first search starting at the points on the outer polygon. And furthermore, if any cycle of length 3 is found (two consecutive points on the outer polygon are both connected to a third point), that can be immediately removed without further searches. Perhaps some example code in C might help? (Although, this is math.stackexchange.com, not stackoverflow.com ...)

Comment: Breadth-first search is not guaranteed to find the smallest polygons. In the example above, it will find you AGXE and AGCE without any indication as to which is the right one. I was thinking of a different approach: traversing the graph like a maze with right-hand rule (find all nodes connected to A, sort by azimuth...), starting from any unused edge, until all edges are used (well, actually, used _twice_, except the outer ones).